# Did Indra or Rama kill Trisiras?

Tags: rama, indra

As you will guess I am very new to hinduist culture. I am doing a bit of research on Trisiras and I am having a hard time figuring out why I sometimes read mentions of Rama killing him, while he is supposed to have been killed by Indra.
Also is there any important event related to Trisiras' life?

Comment: Indra killed Trishiras. Where did you see Raama killing ? Any links?

Comment: @AnuragSingh Aranya Kanda Sarga 27 Rama killing Trishira and in Yuddha Kanda Hanuman killed another Trishira son of Ravana.

Comment: Thanks for your messages : yes here:
[aranya 27] (http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga27/aranya_27_prose.htm) "Rama becoming infuriated eliminates Trishira in the battle."

How should we understand the fact he died twice?

Comment: There is no proof @OliveBooger that this Trishira killed by Raama is the same Trishira, who was son of Tvashtaa, killed by Indra. Because in story of Indra killing Trishira , Trishira is called with names - VishwaRoopa, Tvaashtra, Trishira et cetera. Whereas in the Raama killing story, there is no mention of Tvaashtra(meaning son of Tvashtaa). Again as Triyugi said, that Hanumaan also killed Trishira. Clearly, these 3 Trishira ate different

Comment: Ok, I guess I understand better now. Thank you Anurag and Triyugi !
Ramayana is so complex and exciting.

Answer (score 3):

1)   Viśvarūpa or [Trisiras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisiras), the son of Tvaṣṭā and mentioned in the [Bhagavata Purana](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/7/), was a sage undergoing austerity and penances.  He assisted and advised for overcoming the onslaught of demons.  Later he was killed by Indra.

2) In Ramayana, a demon named [Trishira](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga27/aranya_27_frame.htm), an aide to demon Khara and working under the demon king Ravana, attacked Sri Rama in Janasthana and got killed by the latter.

So both the Trishiras are different, though both were having 3 heads.