# Who is the three headed son of Ravana

Tags: ramayana, rakshasa

In Ashok.K.Banker 's Ramayana he has written that in the forests of Chitrakoot Khara and Dushana were led by a three headed demon named Trisiras leader them against Ram.

> Grieved at the giants' mournful tale, Long, shrill was Atikáya's wail;
> And Tri[irás in sorrow bowed His triple head, and wept aloud. Mahodar,
> Mahápár[va shed Hot tears and mourned their brother dead.

Later he was killed but my question is if such a demon existed ?

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 4):

In the Srimad Valmiki Ramayana, there are two Rakshasas by the name of Trishiras, one being the commander-in-chief of Khara’s army and the other being Ravana’s son. Both are explained below:-

#### 1. Trishiras, a chief in Khara’s army

This Trishira is introduced in the [23rd Sarga](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga23/aranya_23_frame.htm) of the Aranyakanda, while describing the army of Khara that proceeds towards Rama, consequent to Shurpanakha’s insult:

> Mahakapaala, Sthulaaksha, Pramaathi, **Trishira**, these four were at the front of the army and they followed Dushana, marching behind him.

After destroying the 14000 Rakshasa army, only Khara and Trishiras were left, where Trishiras takes Khara’s permission to fight with Rama. Their battle is described in the [27th Sarga](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga27/aranya_27_frame.htm) of the Aranyakanda, where ultimately Rama severs the three heads of the Rakshasa:

> And with three sharp and rapid arrows, and even with his own exasperation, Rama of inestimable aptitude **rolled the three heads that demon**. When that nightwalker is highly tortured with Rama's arrows he collapsed spewing blood with fumes, whereat he is standing in war, at where his **heads** rolled just now.

The killing of Trishiras alongwith Khara and Dushana also finds mention in the Ramacharitmanas during Shurpankha’s lament to Ravana:

> खर दूषन तिसिरा कर घाता। सुनि दससीस जरे सब गाता॥ अरण्यकाण्ड दोहा २२
>
> Hearing that Khara, Dushana and Trishira had been killed, Ravana’s body burned.

#### 2. Trishiras, Ravana’s son

He is one of the seven sons of Ravana and actively participates in the war, after Kumbhakarna’s death. He boosts a lamenting Ravana’s morale by himself offering to head into the war, alongwith his brothers - Devantaka, Narantaka and Atikaya, as described in the [69th Sarga](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga69/yuddha_69_frame.htm) of the Yuddhakanda. He engages with Angada, but ultimately meets his end at the hands of Hanuman, who chops his three heads with a sword, as described in the [70th Sarga](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga70/yuddha_70_frame.htm) of the Yuddhakanda:

> Hanuman became enraged with the blow of Trishiras's fist and caught the crowned head of the demon. Then just as Indra had chopped **the three heads of Tvashta’s son Vishvarupa**, Hanuman chopped off the **three heads of the demon**, furnished with diadems and ear-rings.

Thus we can see that there were two Trishiras in the Ramayana and such demons in fact existed as per the Ramayana. For more information on Tvashta’s son Vishvarupa, [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37452/20129) can be checked.

---

*Note:- wherever the main Sanskrit text and translation, as per the linked website were different from that of Gita Press Gorakhpur, the Gita Press Gorakhpur version has been preferred (though the translations (wherever discrepant) are in blockquotes they represent an English translation of the Gita Press Hindi text by me)*

Answer (score 0):

I think there were two Trishira. One was in army of Khara who had three heads and was [killed](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/aranya/sarga27/aranya_27_prose.htm) by Rama.

> When that nightwalker is vaulting from that smashed chariot Rama with his arrows tore his chest to shreds and he that Trishira became inert. And with three sharp and rapid arrows, and even with his own exasperation, Rama of inestimable aptitude rolled the three heads that demon. That nightwalker who is highly tortured with Rama's arrows has collapsed spewing blood with fumes, whereat he is standing in war, at where his **three heads rolled just now.**

Another Trishira who was Ravana's son was [present](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/yuddha/sarga69/yuddha_69_prose.htm) during **Ram Ravana war**.

> Hearing the words of the evil-minded Ravana, who was thus lamenting, as he was overcome with grief, Trishira (one of his sons) spoke as follows: “Truly in such a manner, the highly valiant Kumbhakarna, (the middle of our father and uncles) has been killed.

There is no reference in Ramyana about three headed son Ravana as far as I know. That three headed Trishira was actually a warrior in Kahra's army.